# meaning of spatter

Tags: meaning

> “Nancy,” directed her mistress, sharply, “you may set the muffins down
>   and go at once to Miss Pollyanna’s room and shut the windows. Shut the
>   doors, also. Later, when your morning work is done, go through every
>   room with the **spatter**. See that you make a thorough search.” – From *Pollyanna*, by Eleanor Porter

Isn’t this ‘spatter’ a mispelling of swatter?
Or spatter itself has some other meaning having something to do with flies?

Comment: OED says ***spatter*** is a variant on obsolete ***spature*** = *spatula* (a kitchen implement used for *stirring*, which Nancy might well have to hand if she's just been making muffins). From the context it seems pretty obvious she'll be using it as a fly-swatter though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it is a word similar in meaning to *[swatter](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/swatter)* but coined in the heat of the moment from the verb root *[to spat](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spat#Verb_4)* - "to strike with a spattering sound". Hence, *spatter* would mean "an implement used to strike something with a spattering sound".

Were it a misspelling, other printed sources of Polyanna would have spelled it as *swatter*, but I've checked several at Google Books and it's *spatter* in each of them.

Comment: So it's a sort of onomatopoeia?

Comment: Yes, it likely is, IMHO.